# How do you use "no way" in a conversation?

Tags: phrase-usage

How do you use "no way" words?

Example: My classmate usually goes to school late. One day she goes to school early. I think surprised can I tell to her "No way!" Is this polite?

Comment: Pointing out to someone how they're always late is *never* polite, no matter what words you use.

Comment: '*No way*' can mean '*I don't believe it*' so if that's your sentiment, you can use it this way. If you're on good terms it might seem like a gentle ribbing, if not it could be rude and impolite.

Answer (score 1):

'**No way!**' can mean '**I don't believe it!**'

If that's your sentiment, you can use it this way.

If you are on good terms it might seem like a gentle ribbing- harmless fun between friends

If not, it would probably be considered rude and impolite.

(Note, there are other ways '*no way*' can be used, but don't seem applicable here)

Answer (score -3):

No way is not polite way, you can use “I don’t think you should” , “had better not”. Also ,we can use  no way with inversion, to emphasize something with negative mining. Example : In no way will you go to that party tonight.